# What is the meaning of the statement. if(!(*tree)). where tree is a node representing the root node of a tree

Tags: c

I got a function for creating a tree as

```
void insert (node *tree, int Val)
{
if(!(*tree)) {
    then it creates a node and assigns its address to pointer variable tree
}
```

I would like to know what does the statement `if(!(*tree))` means

Trying to create a tree recursively.
I didn't get the meaning of the statement I asked above.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be valid but it's hard to tell without seeing a complete piece of code that can be compiled. Please [edit] your question and add one. Use formatting help to make sure code looks like code,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure about the function signature? Is first parameter `node **tree` maybe? WIth only one level of pointer that description does not make sense.

Comment: Or is `node` a typdef hiding a pointer type?

Comment: Are you sure `node *tree` isn't supposed to be `node **tree`?  That would make more sense if `node` is a structure type.  But perhaps `node` is a pointer to a structure?  Show the `typedef` for it.  The posted code isn't complete enough for a reliable answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes .  -Gerhardh.    It was supposed to be.  node **tree.     Thank you.              Can you please tell the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to make sense, the type `node` must represent a pointer to what is usually called a [node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(computer_science)).

A recursive implementation of "insert" would look at the current position given by `*tree` and:

- If a node is present (`*tree != NULL`), decide if the new node should be added in the left or the right subtree of that node and thus call `insert` recursively with the left or right child.
- If no node is present (`*tree == NULL`), create the new node in this position. This is the base case of the recursion.

The expression `!(*tree)` is equivalent to `*tree == NULL`. Hence, the `if`-statement in the question identifies the base case of the recursive function. There must also be an `else`-statement implementing the recursion case.